# error adding single element into structure array java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and having an issue when trying to add a single element into a structure type array.  I have my array setup as so: `public apartment availableRoom[] = new apartment[1];`  My main calls a method that initializes this as soon as the application launches:

```
availableRoom[0] = new apartment(150, 2, 200.00,null);
//this sets default values for room#, beds, price, and guest
```

My constructor takes the info like so

```
public apartment(int roomNum, int beds, double price, String guest )
    { 
        this.roomNumber = roomNum;
        this.roomBeds = beds;
        this.nightlyFee = price;
        this.roomGuest = guest;
    }
```

Where I am having issues is when I am trying to assign a guest to the room.  I am trying it with `availableRoom[i].roomGuest = name`  Name is entered by the user and i is set to 0 (I checked).  No errors but when I go to print the information for the room it returns every value as 0 and the guest to null.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? (FYI Apartment is a separate class from main)

Main

```
public class apartmentMain {


    static apartment action = new apartment();



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        action.createApt();
        action.addGuest();
```

apartment.java

```
public void createApt()
    {
       availableRoom[0] = new apartment(150, 2, 200.00,null);
}

public void addGuest()
{

    name = input.next();
    availableRoom[i].roomGuest = name;

}
```

Comment: You may need to paste the whole code

Comment: No, I don't think anybody can.  This is because you have limited what you have posted.  We can't see the loop, we can't see the declaration of the variables, we don't know how you 'checked' on the value of your index.  Given what your question is, you should be able to construct an entire, executable 'main' class that demonstrates what you're having trouble with in less than twenty lines.  In the process of creating that, you might just discover the answer yourself, and, if not, you can form a much better question.

Comment: pseudo code will be nice

Comment: Without knowing anything really... shouldn't it be `availableRoom[i].roomGuest = name` ?

Comment: How would I go about deleting it and being able to reference the constructor with arguments from the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, as you say

> No errors but when I go to print the information for the room it returns every value as 0 and the guest to null.

I think , you are setting values in diffrent object and printing different one. If you just paste how you are printing its values it may help a lot.

**Things to Consider**

1. Since you are getting default values(that instance variables get if you don't assign any), that means an actual object is there in your                           array, that is instantiated but not initialized.
2. Take a close look which object you are printing and which one you are setting values in.
3. It is quite possible that at the first index, a newly instantiated object is inserted somehow that replaced the original one.
4. you are printing a different object than the original one ....a possibility.
5. You may want to get rid of the "no argument constructor" to better get actual seen of the problem. Try it..its worth.

Comment: It prints fine before I try and add the guest.  Second I call the add guest method and try and print again is when it returns all 0s and null

Comment: have tried removing no argument contructor..? also.you may want to show the code..when you are printing it again..

Comment: I am sorry could you explain what you mean by no argument constructor?

Comment: like this..new apartment()...the constructor which takes no argument..so you have only one constructor which takes values as argument...see the problem is..you are printing an object which are created by this no argument contructor..if you remove it you will get to know what the problem is.

Comment: If I remove it I get an error on my main class that complains about it not having parameters.

Comment: write it as..static apartment action = new apartment(0,0,0, null);..Just for the time being..

Comment: Same result, all 0s and null

Comment: figured it out.  I was trying to put it in the wrong array. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not complete.  I give a small example from which you can guess your error.

```
public class Demo
{
   int x;
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Demo d[] = new Demo[2];
       d[0] = new Demo();
       d[1] = new Demo();

       d[0].x = 100;
       d[1].x = 200;

       System.out.println(d[0].x); 
       System.out.println(d[1].x); 
   }
}
Many people get wrong concept in the following code.
       Demo d[] = new Demo[2];

You think a Demo array of 2 elements (with two Demo objects) with object d is created.  
It is wrong.  Infact, two reference variables of type Demo are created.  The two    
reference variables are to be converted int objects before they are used as follows.
       d[0] = new Demo();
       d[1] = new Demo();

With the above code, d[0] and d[1] becomes objects.  Now check your code in these  
lines.
```

You can find more details from [Java Reference Variables – Objects – Anonymous objects](http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/reference-variables-anonymous-objects)